# Hard drive password reset on Lenovo T520 / secure erase

Tags: hard-drive

I have a Lenovo T520 with a Seagate Momentus Thin self encrypting drive and now I want to remove all encryption so I can use it normally as an external hard drive (USB case for 2½ SATA).

I know the user password for the hard drive (as such I can access its data) but I can't remember the master / supervisor password.

I don't mind losing all data (already backed up), I just want to remove all encryption and use it as a "normal" hard drive.

How can I do this if I only know the user password (BIOS removal of passwords seems to require master password) ?

Comment: Best thing to do would probably be to downloading a USB DOS utility and erase the drive using diskpart - Erasing a drive will remove encryption off it due to the encryption being software based

Comment: @MikeDiglio If it's really a self-encrypting drive, then it stores it's own passwords and does the encryption itself, and it won't let you read or write anything to it without knowing a password. @ AlfaTeK In that case, your best bet is probably to contact Seagate about resetting / setting a new or no password on your drive, or just having it not ask for a password?

Answer (score -1):

Over time I seem to have acquired various hard drives that I wanted to reuse. You do have to remove it, then I have used a docking station plugged into my computer, that the hard drive plugs into. It shows up in computer, or my PC, as another drive number. Then I just use wiping software, (I have used Active@Killdisk, eraser, and Disk Wipe) Then reformat it. You do loose everything and end up with a factory fresh drive. I don't remember ever encountering a password that stopped me from doing it. Just make sure to make it bootable if you want to use it for an O.S. I know I have a choice as to what kind of disk I want to make it.